# Recovering CentOS from bad pam configuration

Tags: centos, ssh, pam

I have a bad PAM configuration got configured on a server.  Attempting to ssh in only gives the error "Authentication Failed" though, verbose mode in SSH shows the authentication being successful.

I am also unable to attain a user/password prompt from an ILO console shell.

Things I am thinking of trying though unsure of are:

1. Can CentOS be installed over itself and preserve data
2. Can I boot into single user mode and fix the configuration
3. Boot from live cd, mount the partitions and fix the configuration
4. Something else

Any guidance other than wipe the whole system would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to boot a LiveCD and fix the configuration.

After booting a live session, mount `/etc` from the dead server on `/mnt`, backup the existing `/etc/pam.d` folder and copy `/etc/pam.d` contents to `/mnt/etc/pam.d`.

After that, reboot the server, load it from the disk, and it should be fine.